# How to make a parallel database change sequential?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am developing a project using WebAPI and Entity Framework 6.

There is a controller with a method that adds a new entity Task to the database. Before add task calculated a unique name for it. Part of the name based on the already saved tasks in the database. If you make two parallel requests, you can generate the same names, this problem is solved through lock.

How can I prevent the generation of identical names if two WebAPI servers are running with a connection to same database?

Is it possible to add the algorithm of adding Task to a sequential queue at the database level?

Simplified code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("add")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddTask()
    {
        using (var db = CreateDbContext())
        {
            Task task = new Task();

            lock (lockAdd)
            {
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

                string preName = dateTime.ToString("yyMMdd-HHmm-");

                var query = db.Tasks.Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith(preName)).Select(t => t.Name);

                List<string> tasksNames = query.ToList();

                task.Name = preName + (tasksNames.Count + 1).ToString("D4");

                db.Tasks.Add(task);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Сolumn "Name" can not be made unique.
Tasks never deleted.
Counter must start from 1 for each new date (new minute).

Comment: Easiest way probably would be to add the logic into the database and return the value from there (maybe an insert trigger). This way it will always be handled properly. Otherwise you'll have to have a unique index anyway and handle exceptions when the same name is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SEQUENCE for generating data on database side. [Docs here](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-createsequence). In this case uniqueness guarant by database.
Or use Guid (UUID) - it provides unique keys. [Docs here](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.6/datatype-uuid) In this case uniqueness guarant by idea of UUIDs

Comment: Counter must start from 1 for each new date (new minute)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, you can also generate the Guid in C#:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The uniqueness is guaranteed as the GUID incorporates both the server time and the server's MAC address. There are some shorter length solutions as well, such as a 64 bit UUID generator like Snowflake. For a C# port example, see:
https://github.com/mschuler/UniqueIdGenerator or https://github.com/ccollie/snowflake-net/blob/master/Snowflake/IdWorker.cs

(Note: if you use a singleton Snowflake generator, you only need a lock on the ID generator since the uniqueness is guaranteed by an incremental counter inside the same millisecond for up to 2^12 IDs / ms / server. The second source already comes with a lock in it for this).

Comment: Counter must start from 1 for each new date (new minute), .

Comment: In that case, what you really need is not an application lock but a transaction with a serializable write lock: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html